# Some misunderstand in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I have this definition:

```
var self = this;
this.game= gameArchive;
```

I have this row in my view:

```
<input type="checkbox"
    checklist-model="builderStep2.game.ModelItems"
    checklist-value="model.Id"> {{model.Name}}
```

where `builderStep2` is controller name.

And also I have this row code:

```
self.game.ModelItems.push(someID);
```

When user press on the check button the array is created and the value is added to `game.ModelItems`, but when I try to fill the array programmatically by this row:

```
self.game.ModelItems.push(someID);
```

it seems that array is not creates and I get this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null`

Any idea why does it happen?

Answer (score 3):

`push()` belongs to `Array.prototype`. If `game.ModelItems` is not an array, `push()` will not work.

I'm not sure what `gameArchive` is doing, but you could try in your controller `this.game.ModelItems = [];` and I have a feeling `push()` would work.

Comment: its also possible that ModelItems isn't even declared.. but yes I agree your solution would help with that..

Comment: Simply declaring "this.game.ModelItems;" isn't going to do anything. It needs to be defined as an array with "= [];" or an equivalent alternative.

Comment: this.game.ModelItems is declared but it not declared as array.But when I use this approach <input type="checkbox"
    checklist-model="builderStep2.game.ModelItems"
    checklist-value="model.Id">  it's working?

Comment: yeh you need to initialize it to an empty array like ModelItems = new Array() or ModelItems= []. Your ModelItems is simply null, and your javascript is throwing an error because it can't access a property of a null value. In your case, "push" is the property. If you switch ModelItems from null to an array, then it'll work.